# SQL to_char() printing 2 digit number as 0xx and not touching 3 number digit

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently battling with something
that must be trivial for you.

I have 2 number 191 and 97, and I need to put them in a SQL request, as chars and 97 must be printed as 097.

At first I tried 999, but it added 2 space to my numbers.
then 099, it does print 097 but it adds a space to it.

```
to_char(:center, '099') = " 197" and " 097"
```

Where is this space coming from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Format Modifier element:

```
to_char(:center, 'fm099')
```

Answer (score 3):

The leading space is for the potential minus sign. To remove it you can use `FM` in the format:

```
to_char(v_num,'FM099')
```

Answer (score 0):

9  9999 Returns value with the specified number of digits with a leading space if positive or with a leading minus if negative.Leading zeros are blank, except for a zero value, which returns a zero for the integer part of the fixed-point number.

From http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510

Use @DavidAldridge solution, or trim your value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the all column values in same number of digits even the actual value having less digits. Try this

```
a) SELECT TO_CHAR(COLUMN_NAME, 'FM099') FROM TABLE_NAME;

b) SELECT TO_CHAR(COLUMN_NAME, 'FM000') FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Both is working fine. but don't know which one would be the best choice.